# exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have code spring+hibernate using oracle database. I have setting the configuration but i still get an error like :

```
 cannot Deploy Spring3HibernateApp
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]. Please see server.log for more details.
```

i have create database.properties like this:

```
database.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1521:xxx
database.user=xxxx
database.password=welcome1
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

When i try in ADF, the program is running.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Add the oracle jdbc driver jar to your classpath.

Comment: The important part of the error is: *Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to downloar oracl JDBC Driver from this link :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc101040-094982.html

accept License  and then choose

```
ojdbc14.jar
```

after download, copy the jar file and then past it in your classpath/lib folder